# Validate XML against XSD and ignore order of child elements

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I have a method in a C# app that validates a user input XML file against an embedded XSD.  It works just fine, but it requires that all the child elements be in the exact order defined in the XSD.  To me though, the order doesn't matter so long as the elements exist.

For example, if I had the following XSD...

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ParentElement">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="FirstChildElement" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="SecondChildElement" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="ThirdChildElement" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And an XML like this...

```
<ParentElement>
    <FirstChildElement>someValue</FirstChildElement>        
    <ThirdChildElement>someValue</ThirdChildElement>
    <SecondChildElement>someValue</SecondChildElement>
</ParentElement>
```

If I validated it I'd get an error because the child elements are out of order.

Can I make some change to the XSD so validation only cares if the elements exist, and that they're under the correct parent, but not what order they're in?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sequence means, the elements must appear in the specific order. You probably want xs:all. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer.  My XSD was generated for me by VS, so it had everything the child elements under a Sequence tag.

Comment: Point to remember is that xs:all only supports a maxOccurs of 1 and not more than that. This however has been lifted in XSD 1.1 processor, which is still at the beta stage.

Comment: Did they ever release 1.1?